# Spy object keeps calling to real method even when stubbed

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, stub, spy

I am working on unit testing this service method, which requires using other methods in the same class that is being tested. So I have read about `spy` and applied it to my code. However, even when stubbed, the spy object of the class that I am testing keeps executing the real methods.

The method that is being tested

```
@Override
    public CategoryResponseDto updateCategory(Long categoryId, UpdateCategoryRequestDto requestDto) {
        CategoryEntity categoryEntity = findById(categoryId);

        modelMapper.convertToEntity(requestDto, categoryEntity);
        categoryEntity = categoryRepository.save(categoryEntity);

        return modelMapper.convertToResponse(categoryEntity, CategoryResponseDto.class);
    }
```

My code to test it

```
    @Test
    public void updateCategory_ShouldReturnCategoryResponseDto_WhenDataValid() {
        CategoryEntity categoryEntity = mock(CategoryEntity.class);
        UpdateCategoryRequestDto requestDto = mock(UpdateCategoryRequestDto.class);
        CategoryCrudServiceImpl spy = Mockito.spy(categoryCrudService);
        CategoryResponseDto expectedResult = mock(CategoryResponseDto.class);

        doReturn(categoryEntity).when(spy).findById(anyLong());
        when(categoryRepository.save(categoryEntity)).thenReturn(categoryEntity);
        when(modelMapper.convertToResponse(categoryEntity, CategoryResponseDto.class)).thenReturn(expectedResult);

        CategoryResponseDto result = categoryCrudService.updateCategory(1L, requestDto);

        assertThat(result, is(expectedResult));
    }
```

So the class being tested here is `CategoryCrudServiceImple`, the instance of that class is `categoryCrudService` in my test code and I create a spy out of it `spy(categoryCrudService)`. As you can see, I stubbed the `findById()` which comes from the same `CategoryCrudServiceImple` class with `doReturn(categoryEntity).when(spy).findById(1L);` and It didn't work, I tried passing in `any()` or `anyLong()` and the real `findById()` method is still called and throws the exception of `ResourceNotFound`.

Could you please help me with this? Am I missing or misunderstanding anything here?

Thank you very much for your precious time.

Comment: Why do you assume `categoryCrudService.updateCategory(1L, requestDto)` works with the spy? You're not using the spy there.

Comment: This where I am calling the method to test, I am not stubbing here. Am I supposed to use spy here? I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, using spy there did solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to the above comment of @Tom, I managed to get it right because I did not use spy here `CategoryResponseDto result = categoryCrudService.updateCategory(1L, requestDto);`. It should be like this `CategoryResponseDto result = spy .updateCategory(1L, requestDto);`.